# Gruvbox color-scheme not working in tmux-sessoin but working working in normal iterm2

Tags: tmux, iterm2

[these values are in my tmux-session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzoDI.png)
I have tried changing these values.

Answer (score 0):

```
>\# ColorScheme settings.  
set -g default-terminal "xterm-256color".  
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",tmux-256color:Tc,xterm256color:Tc"
```

Adding these lines in the ./tmuxconfig worked.